# I wrote some code which is mentioned below , but how can i delete column heading row from second file onwards after merging two files

Tags: regex, linux, shell

**File Name: first.txt**

id name contact

1  abc  7679876789

2  bcd  9867363675

**File Name: second.txt**

id name contact

3  cde  7979436789

4  bgb  9845363675

After merging both files(**first.txt and second.txt**), I got following output :

id name contact

1  abc  7679876789

2  bcd  9867363675

id name contact

3  cde  7979436789

4  bgb  9845363675

**But I want output like follow :**

id name contact

1  abc  7679876789

2  bcd  9867363675

3  cde  7979436789

4  bgb  9845363675

So I need to remove second file first column id row.

Comment: How are you going through the file?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you but create new file

```
  cat file1.txt file2.txt | awk '!seen[$0]++'>file3.txt
```

Comment: This will not only purge the header line, but also all other duplicate records.

Comment: As per the requirement i just give a shot, and this script will purge only the duplicate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the header line when you are merging:

```
awk 'FNR==1 && NR > FNR {next}; 1'  first.txt second.txt
```

This is easier than merging, look for a line like the first line and remove that line.

Wehen both files have the same header and the header is not a data row, you can use

```
awk 'remembered==$0 {next} FNR==1 {remembered=$0} 1'  combined.txt
```

Without awk you need to do more processing like using `head -1` for finding the line you want to skip and process like this

```
sed '1p; /id name contact/d' combined.txt

# Or with headrow=$(sed -1q combined.txt)
sed "1p; /$headrow/d" combined.txt
```

Comment: sed '1p; /id name contact/d' combined.txt it is ok but it can delete all rows which matching with id name contact right. but i need to remove those rows from second file not first file

Comment: After combining it is hard to tell what lines are part of the first file. So try merging the correct lines only, something line `cat first.txt <(sed '1d' second.txt) > combined.txt` or the `awk` above.

Comment: But my side we can extract similar named files from directory,then store those file names into one file, we can extract those names one by one,  apply cat on that file name then merging the data which has same file names into one final single file**(FinalMerge.txt)**

Comment: All.txt contains file names like first.txt and second.txt so I need to extract these two files from All.txt file then merge into one file(FinalMerge.txt). So while reading file names from All.txt file,  I got problem that removing second file header line(first row).

Comment: When you extracted second.txt use awk or sed for removing the first line.